# How to compare fast the value with the ones of neighbours in a 3D array

Tags: python, bigdata, numpy

### Question:

I want to compare every item in a 3D array with its first neighborhoods. It's really slow when I have a 500x500x500 (e.g. with only values of 0, 1, 2) ndarray. I post the **principle lines** here:

```
import numpy as np

# Create a list to stock all the neighbours' coordinations of the voxel wanted 
def check_neighbor(array, x, y, z):
   #top
   t = array[x, y , z + 1]
   #down
   d = array[x, y , z - 1]
   #left
   l = array[x, y - 1 , z]
   #right
   r = array[x, y + 1 , z]
   #front
   f = array[x - 1, y , z]
   #back
   b = array[x + 1, y , z]
   return [t, d, l, r, f, b]

# Check the voxel with all its neighborhood
def compare_neighbor(array, Value2match, Value2Bmatched):
   for index in np.argwhere(array==Value2match)
      output[index] = 1 if Value2BMatched in checkneighbor(array, index[0],index[1], index[2]) else 0 
   return output

# Main
array = np.random.randint(3, shape=(500, 500, 500))
output = compare_neighbor(array, 1, 2)
```

This code take me hours only for the n=1 neighbour! Is there an efficient way which can also check the 2, 3... nearest neighbours? Can somebody help me?

## Solution 1:

Based on **jayprich**'s answer and **n1k31t4**'s comments, I fused the both function into one and replace the `argwhere()` by `where()`. The **advantage** of this code is that we **don't iterate voxel by voxel** but do it in a vectorized way:

```
import numpy as np
# Build a helper function to SHIFT(not roll) a 3Darray
def shift_helper(array, neib_value, shift=0, axis=0):
    #Roll the 3D array along axis with certain unity
    _array = np.roll(array == neib_value, shift=shift, axis=axis)

    # Cancel the last/first slice shifted to the first/last slice
    if axis == 0:
        if shift >= 0:
            _array[:1, :, :] = 0
        else:
            _array[-1:, :, :] = 0
        return _array
    elif axis == 1:
        if shift >= 0:
            _array[:, :1, :] = 0
        else:
            _array[:, -1:, :] = 0
        return _array
    elif axis == 2:
        if shift >= 0:
            _array[:, :, :1] = 0
        else:
            _array[:, :, -1:] = 0
        return _array


def compneib(array, that_value, neib_value):
    _array = np.zeros(array.shape)
    _array[np.where((array == that_value)
                    & (shift_helper(array, neib_value, shift=-1, axis=0)
                    | shift_helper(array, neib_value, shift=1, axis=0)
                    | shift_helper(array, neib_value, shift=-1, axis=1)
                    | shift_helper(array, neib_value, shift=1, axis=1)
                    | shift_helper(array, neib_value, shift=-1, axis=2)
                    | shift_helper(array, neib_value, shift=1, axis=2)
                    ))] = 1
    return _array

# Main
array = np.random.randint(3, shape=(500, 500, 500))
output = compneib(array, 1, 2)
```

## Solution 2:

If there would still be a faster way.

Comment: What is `output` exactly, within `compare_neighbor`? You have not initialised it. Also, is there an upper limit on the integer contents of your main input array?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. It's true that I just showed the principle lines. Output is a np.ndarray. Then I did a zero-padding of one layer to the surface of the matrix in order to avoiding the out of range from the check_neighbor function

Comment: I think you are on the right lines, using an approach like @jayprich's. Your **Solution 1** code does not work though, as there are basic copy/paste errors I think. Can you fix it? Also, is there an upper limit on the integer values that can be present in your input array?

Comment: @n1k31t4 thanks for your remark. I edited and added a helper function to remove the lowest or toppest slice. Please try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy performs operations in a vectorised manner, you should try and operate on the whole array and avoid explicit loops.

e.g. `np.argwhere( (test == 1) & np.roll( test==2 , shift=-1 , axis=0 ) )`

can be done for different shift and axis values and results combined

Comment: Thanks, I tested but it's still very slow. `np.argwhere((array == 1) & (np.roll(array == 2, shift=-1, axis=0) | np.roll(array == 2, shift=1, axis=0) | np.roll(array == 2, shift=-1, axis=1) | np.roll(array == 2, shift=1, axis=1) | np.roll(array == 2, shift=-1, axis=2) | np.roll(array == 2, shift=1, axis=2)))`

Comment: The np.where() works better than the argwhere(). I edited the question